# Error updating buildToolsVersion 21.0.2 to 22.0.1

Tags: java, android, build-tools

Recently addded this:

**buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'**

I am using different productFlavors.

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.consulta'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 14
        versionName '1.0.11'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("keystore.jks")
            storePassword "******"
            keyAlias "MyAlias"
            keyPassword "******"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        production {
            applicationId "com.app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "MyApp"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 22
        }
        stage {
            applicationId "com.app.stage"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "MyApp.Stage"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 22
        }
        freeze {
            applicationId "com.app.freeze"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "MyApp.Freeze"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 22
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' 
}
```

Here are the errors:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexStageRelease' UNEXPECTED
>   TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>
> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536        at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>         at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)         at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)         at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)         at
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Answer (score 0):

You've found the mythological 65k method hard cap

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html